# Missing opencv_world310d.dll when running my program

Tags: opencv

I tried to run a simple sample code. But It gave me the following error:

> The program can't start because **opencv_world310d.dll** is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I tried a lot of ways, but they didn't work, such as checking whether to set environment, adding Additional Dependencies in the Property manager, and so on. BTW, I'm using **visual studio 2015** with **opencv 3.1**.

Comment: Copy the dll in the same folder where is your executable ($(SolutionDir)\Debug), or add the folder where is your dll to system PATH

Comment: @Miki Thank your help and I solved this problem. But I want to know why I didn't meet with this problem.

Comment: @Miki I guess it is because of upgrade of my system(windows 10), isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the dll in the same folder where is your executable ($(SolutionDir)\Debug), or add the folder where is your dll to system PATH.